# Native XOR-Support: xor-DPLL(to_examine)

Tags: boolean-logic, xor, solver, propagation, satisfiability

[image: pseudo code of the xor-DPLL]

Does anyone here understand the code and is able to answer a few of my question towards it?

For info: 
`to_examine` is a queue and saves variables which are recently assigned.
`var` is obviously a variable, it's going to be examined whether it causes a conflict, a propagation or nothing.

What I don't understand is how `DPLL(var)` is returning a clause in line 3, I thought DPLL can just return true or false.

And how/why does the DPLL algorithm accepts just a single variable in line 3?

The source of this pseudo code is the PHD thesis of Mate Soos from 2009.

Comment: [Mate Soos](https://www.msoos.org/about/) might be prepared to answer this question.

Comment: `clause` is the *conflict-clause* associated with the `unsat-core` that is found by the DPLL when the stack of formulas is unsatisfiable. The notation `DPLL(var)` likely denotes the fact that `var` is decided as an assumption by the DPLL solver.